# use 'constants' or 'type' for MySQL statement

Tags: mysql, sql

I have DB(in  MySQL) that looks like:

```
CREATE TABLE tbl1(... ,title VARCHAR(69) DEFAULT("new title"), ...);
CREATE TABLE tbl3(... ,title VARCHAR(69) DEFAULT("new title"), ...);
CREATE TABLE tbl3(... ,title VARCHAR(69) DEFAULT("new title"), ...);
```

The question is: **Is there any way how to don't repeat the values(66,"new title") many times ?**
Thanks !

I already have tried 2 solutions, but they doesn’t works.

1-

```
SET @title_len=69,@title_def="new title";
CREATE TABLE tbl1(... ,title VARCHAR(@title_len) DEFAULT(@title_def), ...);
```

2-

```
CREATE TYPE TitleType FROM VARCHAR(69) DEFAULT("new title");
CREATE TABLE tbl1(... ,title TitleType, ...);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create first table, e.g. -

```
CREATE TABLE tbl1(column1 INT, column2 INT);
```

Then use [CREATE TABLE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-table.html) statement with **LIKE** option to duplicate table structure -

```
CREATE TABLE tbl2 LIKE tbl1;
CREATE TABLE tbl3 LIKE tbl1;
...
```